# Qt : How to emit QNetworkReply Slot after QNetworkRequest accoumplish?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2010, qt4.8

I am trying to use multiple threads to request data from cloud. My problem is  after the QnetworkReply finishes replyFinished(QnetworkReply*) slot never emitted. How do i do this ?

**pc_gateway.h**

```
//Main class 
#include "dhvac_datacollector_thread.h"

class PC_Gateway : public QMainWindow
{
   Q_OBJECT 

    DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread *m_DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread[70]; 

    PC_Gateway(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~PC_Gateway();

   public slots:
      void slot_start_comm(); 
};
```

**pc_gateway.cpp**

```
#include "pc_gateway.h"

PC_Gateway::PC_Gateway(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
: QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{

}

PC_Gateway::~PC_Gateway()
{

}

void PC_Gateway::slot_start_comm()
{
    int nNumOfThreads = 4;

    for(int i=0; i<nNumOfThreads ; i++)
    {
       this->m_DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread[i] = new DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread(this);
       this->m_DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread[i]->start();
    } 
}
```

**DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread.h**

```
//Thread class
class DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
      DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread(QObject *parent);
      ~DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread();

      void run();
      void Stop();

    public slots:
       void replyFinished(QNetworkReply*);
};
```

**DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread.cpp**

```
#include "dhvac_datacollector_thread.h"

DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread::DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread(QObject *parent)
: QThread(parent)
{

}

DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread::~DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread()
{
}

void DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread::run()
{
    while(true)
    {
        QString sUrl = "https://api.uno.taww.com/api/v2/data/sensor/"+sNodeId+"/10m/_";  
        QUrl url(sUrl);
        bool bUrl = url.isValid(); 

        if(!bUrl) //If URL is invalid
         return false;

        QNetworkRequest request;    
        request.setUrl(url);    
        request.setRawHeader("api_token","eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9");
        request.setRawHeader("user_id","102473df5c9106e55d");
        request.setRawHeader("cache-control","no-cache");

       QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
       connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,
               SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
       QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
    }
}

void DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)  
{
  QByteArray responseData;
  if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
  {
    responseData = reply->readAll();
    QString sData (responseData);
    reply->close();
    reply->deleteLater();
    qDebug()<<"Raw data:" <<sData;  

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try send your requests after receiving reply, in your `replyFinished` slot not in a loop. Just do one request, if `replyFinished` works fine that way then do the second request.

```
void DHVAC_DataCollector_Thread::replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)  
{
    QByteArray responseData;
    if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        responseData = reply->readAll();
        QString sData (responseData);
        reply->close();
        reply->deleteLater();
        qDebug()<<"Raw data:" <<sData;  
    }
    // nextRequest()
}
```

Also you have a leak. You are creating tons of `QNetworkAccessManager` and never releasing.